# What laptops support RAID-1 mirroring?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive, raid, raid-1

What currently available laptops support RAID-1 mirroring or other RAID configuration?

Laptops with more than 1 internal hard-drive bay:

- HP8530
- ...

*(This is very similar to a previous question
["how to tell if a laptop can have two harddisks"](https://superuser.com/questions/70493/how-to-tell-if-a-laptop-can-have-two-harddisks).
Should we merge them?)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenovo W700 and W710 as far as I know. Also a Dell workstation (just read about it in the news, its a new machine, 17" , orange color, supports raid and comes with i7.)

(Maybe you can set up software raid on any thinkpad if you add a sata drive into the Ultrabay. Never tried this method.)

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Any laptop with 2 harddrives will support a software-raid1.  I don't recommend Raid-1 as a backup solution for laptops, because both harddrives could break if you dropped it or it got stepped on.  I would recommend an online backup tool like carbonite.com to backup your important data.

Comment: I probably should have phrased my question better -- I guess what I really want to know is:
What laptops support 2 internal hard drives?
Is lugging around one (or even 2) external hard drives a good idea?

Comment: You haven't told us why you want raid/externals, so I cannot tell you if it is a good idea.  You should specify what you are trying to do and I can help give better suggestions.  If there are particular files you want to not lose, and you have internet most places, I would suggest online backup... normally you don't want all your backups in the same place (what if your laptop and externals get stolen?).  Unless you have your own home server you can synchronize to, you should use one of the online backup services.

Answer (score 1):

My Dell Inspiron 1721 has two internal drive bays.